# WP: Showing products from another DB using WP-Permalinks and PageTemplate?

Tags: wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite, permalinks

would love to get your help with this.

**My IS situation:**
So I have my users create their own product. Lets say its an outfit containing a tie, a shirt and a shoe. I allow them to save this outfit. My script saves the picture and some more info about the outfit in a database which is not connected to wordpress.  In my DB each outfit has it own unique ID. It also has a name.

**My TO BE situation:**
Firstly I want the name and ID in that outfit to be put into the URL.
So I the user will be able to link to his newly created outfit.
The desired URL schema is:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/outfits/funky-shirt-blue-tie-outfit/o12345
```

or :

```
http://www.mydomain.com/outfits/{%outfitTitle%}/o{%outfitID%}
```

Secondly I want to use wordpress page- or post-templates to display the outfit picture.

**My PROBLEM:**
- I dont want to create a page/post for each outfit.
- Each outfit is not stored as a page or post in wordpress database.

**What I did find so far:**
I found a mod rewrite tool http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/
I read those docs http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type
and http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy but dont get anywhere.

Anybody who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll have to deal with custom rewrite rules and custom query_vars. Otherwise it is simple.

First of all, create custom page template. It is simple as creating php file which includes, at least, this code:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Outfit */ ?>
```

Than you can create a page in your WP admin and assign it your new page template. Note this page ID. You'll need it later on!

Now, let's register custom rewrite rules. To register custom rewrite rules, you'll have to add this code to your functions.php

```
add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'outfit_rewrite_rules' );
function outfit_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite )
{
    $outfit_page_id = 3; //get ID of your page with custom template for displaying outfit
    $wp_rewrite->rules = array(
        'outfit/?([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => $wp_rewrite->index . '?page_id='. $outfit_page_id .'&outfit_ename=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index( 1 ) . '&outfit_id=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index( 2 ),
    ) + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
```

This code will rewrite all traffic containing outfit in URL to your custom page, created in step 1, with custom page template and will include 'outfit_name' and 'outfit_id' in -URL. But to access these variables, you have to register custom query vars. By this code, again in functions.php of your template

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'outfit_query_vars' );
function outfit_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'outfit_name';
    $vars[] = 'outfit_id';
    return $vars;
}
```

Then, you will be able to acceess them in your custom page template by this code:

```
$outfit_id = get_query_var('outfit_id');
$outfit_name = get_query_var('outfit_name');
```

Than it is easy to connect to your DB and get desired entries, ist't it? Your PHP code for entering DB will be in your outfit page template - after opening comment.

Comment: Thanks david.binda this works with one thing missing: I had to update the permalinks structure after making above changes. TOP!